# Unhide dock on fullscreen apps faster (with mouse)

Tags: catalina, mouse, dock, trackpad, fullscreen

I'm a new Mac user and I'm currently MacOS Catalina.

My question is how to unhide the dock on fullscreen apps without having to drag the mouse a lot further down than usual to get the dock. It doesn't show dock until I drag my cursor way way down.

I understand with trackpad, I can simply move my cursor to bottom and keep touching the trackpad to get the dock but it is really difficult to get the dock using mouse (since I can't really give a "touch" feedback)

Comment: You don't need touch feedback with a mouse, you just drag quickly, which invokes the acceleration. The cursor cannot go below the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I agree we cannot go beyond the bottom of screen. I perhaps didn't write it well, I meant that I have to drag my mouse further down. And I tried dragging the mouse quickly on fullscreen apps. Still no luck, I still have to drag my mouse further down to invoke the dock.